# Preview.app print dialog missing Quality and Color vs Black & White?

Tags: pdf, preview, printing, color

I just upgraded to macOS Ventura and now the Preview.app doesn't seem to have a Print Quality option or a Color vs Black & White option when I'm printing from Preview.

The only weird thing I notice in the Print dialog (shown below) is that it says my HP OfficeJet is using a Laser Printer driver.

I've tried removing and reinstalling the printer a couple of times and it ends up the same way each time.

Mac Studio 2022, Ventura 13.0.1
HP OfficeJet Pro 9020 Series

[image: screenshot of print dialog from Preview.app]

The file I'm trying to print is inherently black and white, so I thought that might be part of the problem. So I opened a color image in Preview.app and tried to print it. It turns it into black and white in the print preview and doesn't offer me the Quality or Color vs Black/White either:

[image: screenshot of preview with color image]

[image: screenshot of print dialog showing the color image in black/white]

Any idea where it is or why the Print Quality and Color/Black&White might be missing?

Comment: Yes, looks like you're using generic PCL mono print drivers. When you add the printer, make sure that you specify the correct print drivers.

Comment: @benwiggy How? When I add the printer it picks all of that stuff automatically. It doesn't give me an option.

Comment: Ok, I removed and re-added the printer about 6 more times and finally on the 6th time it finally said the drivers were 9020. I have no idea what they screwed up in Ventura. :(

Comment: Even if Preview.app is among the lousiest PDF viewers out there, this looks more like an issue with the printer driver.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings on Mac, head over to Printers and Scanners and ‘remove’ the printer you just added. Now ‘Add a New Printer..’ and select the same new printer from the list and add it back.
That’s it. You should be able to see things in colour and will preview and print in colour.

Comment: My setup has [the same issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/468745/old-macbook-air-running-big-sur-macos-11-7-cant-print-color-my-partners-pc-do). This tactic was unavailing.