# Old MacBook Air running Big Sur macOS 11.7 can't print color; my partner's PC does so easily

Tags: printing, color, driver

My partner has a Brother MFC-9340CDW color printer; she can easily print in color from her PC running Windows. My MacBook Air, running macOS 11.7, can only print in black and white.  Both computers connect easily via wifi.

I have updated the Brother printer's firmware, and tried the latest Brother software offered for the Mac, macOS 10.5.  The print dialog on the computer screen has no option for black-and-white/color.

Both my computer and the printer are old; my MacBook Air is mid-2013, and the Brother printer is "discontinued."

Have any of you found a workaround for what looks like a printer driver issue?

Comment: does it displays the print preview in color. If you save it as pdf is it in color

Comment: According to they web site it only supports OSX 10.xx not OSX 11... and Windows up to 11

Comment: Yes, the print preview appears in color. Yes, Brother's website stops with macOS 10.x. I've wrestled with this sort of old-equipment challenge in the past, but am out of ideas here.

Comment: If you save it as PDF in color and then print the pdf what happens

Comment: The saved .pdf image is in color. The print preview is in B&W. The print is in B&W.

Comment: When you add the printer, it says "Name, Location, Use", and the "Use" gives you a drop-down with choices of the driver to use. Make sure that you select the drivers for your printer; if those don't work, see if using Airprint or generic driver will work.

Comment: The latest drivers look like being from 2019, for Catalina - at least they should be 64-bit - https://www.brother.co.uk/support/mfc9340cdw/downloads

Comment: @Tetsujin That Catalina software was the first workaround I tried. It produced the same B&W-only result.

Comment: @benwiggy Airprint does not appear on the drop-down, although the printer manual suggests that Airprint would work with my iPhone. I don't need to do that.

Comment: What about a Generic PostScript driver? (Or PCL6)?